# Client unable to connect to Server in python using socket

Tags: python, sockets

I am creating a program that requires a client and a server to track player locations in pygame.
I use this class for the networking in the client:

```
class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server = "0.0.0.0"
        self.port = 5555
        self.addr = (self.server, self.port)
        self.pos = self.connect()

    def getPos(self):
        return self.pos

    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.client.connect(self.addr)
            return self.client.recv(2048).decode()
        except:
            pass

    def send(self, data):
        try:
            self.client.send(str.encode(data))
            return self.client.recv(2048).decode()
        except socket.error as e:
            print(e)
```

To format the data to be sent and received by the server I am using:

```
def read_pos(str):
    print(str)
    print(type(str))
    return json.loads(str)  # returns as tuple


def make_pos(tup):
    return json.dumps(tup)
```

Within the main function I create a network object (n) and then use n.connect() to the server, no errors occur. However, on the following line the following error occurs:

```
raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType
```

This is the main function where the code fails:

```
def main():  # asking server for updates, checking for events
    n = Network()
    n.connect()
    startPos = read_pos(n.getPos())
```

Upon investigation, I can see the client has not connected to the server. Therefore, when the str being passed to read_pos is a NoneType which is where the error is coming from. What is preventing the client from connecting to the server?

Comment: Where is the missing code that actually fails? Also not a good idea to name a variable `str` because it shadows the Python string type.

Comment: Your connect method swallows exceptions, which is a poor practice. It should at least log/print the error. It should either re-throw the exception or the calling code should test for the implicit None return value. Once you've corrected that, what happens?

Comment: The error returned is: return self.client.recv(2048).decode()
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Comment: When the client is ran for a second time. A connection is made but then is lost immediately

Comment: @StratCharl that means the server closed the connection.

Comment: The error i am now receiving is:     self.client.connect(self.addr)
OSError: [WinError 10056] A connect request was made on an already connected socket

Comment: Once you've resolved your connectivity issues, I'd suggest rethinking your Network methods. Your `connect` method, for example, connects (good) and then returns data (unexpected). That's not intuitive, given the method name. Your `send` methods both sends and receives data. Same issue.